# Finding The First Empty Row At The End Of The Column And Pasting Data In It, Excel VB

Tags: vb.net, excel

```
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = oSheet.Range("A4000").End("Excel.XlDirection.XlUp").Row + 1
    oSheet.Range("A" + LastRow).Value = "TEST"
    oSheet.Range("B" + LastRow).Value = "TEST"
```

- An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
- Additional information: Conversion from string "Excel.XlDirection.XlUp" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from your Xlup parameter, and use `&` to concatenate strings instead of `+`.

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = oSheet.Range("A4000").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1
oSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = "TEST"
oSheet.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = "TEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the amount of used rows, you should be able to use this:

```
Dim lastRow as Integer = oSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

To do a single value or cell, you can just do this:

```
oSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).value = "Test"
oSheet.Cells(lastRow, 2).value = "Test"
```

Comment: There is an end of statement expected after the 2DArray + I still have the conversion problem?

Comment: @HudsonWY That was just an example, you don't have anything declared as 2DArray. See my edit (to clear it up)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to find the LASTROW in the excel sheet and by adding 1 to this LASTROW we can find the EMPTYROW

'The program starts here

```
Private Sub f_ExcelWorksheet()
        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Object
        Dim oSheet As Object

        'Start a new workbook in Excel
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add


        'Add data to cells of the first worksheet in the new workbook
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
        oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Last Name"
        oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "First Name"
        oSheet.Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        oSheet.Range("A2").Value = "Doe"
        oSheet.Range("B2").Value = "John"
        'This will find the lastRow in the sheet
        Dim lastRow As Integer = oSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        'This is next emptyRow in the sheet
        Dim emptyRow As Integer = lastRow + 1
        MessageBox.Show(lastRow)
        oSheet.Cells(emptyRow, 1).value = "Test"
        oSheet.Cells(emptyRow, 2).value = "Test"
        'Now again find the lastRow in the excel sheet
        lastRow = oSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        'This is next emptyRow in the sheet
        emptyRow = lastRow + 1

        'Save the Workbook and Quit Excel
        oBook.saveas("C:\Users\adimadud\Desktop\Test.xlsx")
        oExcel.Quit()

    End Sub
```